# Why I cannot use HttpResponseMessage class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, reference, cs0246

I'm new to ASP.NET Web API and want to make `HttpResponseMessage` instance from a utility class I made. Then I made very simple class.

But following compile error occurred.

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpResponseMessage' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace myapplication.App_Code.Utils
{
    public class HttpUtility
    {
        // compile error here
        public HttpResponseMessage GetHttpResponseMessage ()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

`HttpResponseMessage` is available from Controller Class which was made automatically by ASP.NET but not my Utility class.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this class placed in a different project than your API project?

Comment: You can use it, provided you add the appropriate assembly reference. The error message explains as much. Check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx)  for the class and add the appropriate assembly. It's right next to the bold `Assembly:` tag right after the heading

Comment: @IzzetYildirim it is  same project.

Comment: The assembly is "System.Net.Http.dll" and it is already referenced, but it is only available only from Controller class, not my utility class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that you placed your class in `App_Code` folder in your project. [This folder has a special purpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) in ASP.NET world and should be used for shared classes and business objects that you want to compile as part of your application. So either move your class into another folder, or change its `Build Action` in properties section to `Compile`.